# Splicing out a single pair of wires from buck converter for 2 Arduinos and buttons

Tags: wire, wire-terminals, terminal-block

I'll need to use my 15W 12-5 buck converter to power both Arduinos and for triggering 3-4 buttons. The buck has a pair of wires on the output so I'm trying to figure out what's the most tidy and solid way to splice the one + wire for multiple outputs. Would Wago splices be considered good solution, ok, hack? Any other suggestions?

[image]

Comment: No single thing (like Wago connectors) represents everywhere *"the most tidy and solid way to splice the one + wire for multiple outputs".* Wago is great for cases where the wire diameter is always the same and matched with the connector and where you often need to revisit the connection, changing something frequently. (This is why it may be overkill when used in an mains outlet, since you don't often change things there.) But as they say, to one with a chainsaw everything looks like a tree. You can do a lot with WAGO, I suppose.

Comment: Your vote would go to soldering, if I can take a guess? :)

Comment: No. I'm just saying that Wago may be one tool in your box. But it shouldn't be considered the only tool. In fact, I have them here as well. But I rarely decide to use one, even with them here in boxes. (I had thought I might use them more often than I've actually found a need for, I guess.) I'd use them for cases where I had, say, lots of 18 gauge wires hanging from boards and from power sources and where I wanted to connect *this board* to *that power supply*. So in your diagram, the left three wires make sense to me assuming your two 'Ardu' devices had power wires hanging from them.